# How to disable custom plugin in admin

Tags: magento2, module, custom, system.xml, system-config

I have created a custom module to disable free shipping based on some conditions. I have to used

Custom/ShippingRule/Plugin/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php to do the functionality.

It is working fine now. I want to enable/disable this from admin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the 100% solution. But might below one can be a solution.

Suppose your **di.xml** which is exist at `app/code/{vendor}/{moduleFolder}/etc` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
      <plugin name="my_plugin_name" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

To disable this plugin  at **adminhtml** area, create `di.xml` at `app/code/{vendor}/{moduleFolder}/etc/adminhtml` and  disabled that plugin by plugin name `my_plugin_name` like below:\

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
      <plugin name="my_plugin_name"  disabled="true" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: I want to disable from admin not programatically.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create **system.xml** file in your module.
Path for this file is app/code/{vendor}/{modulename}/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="tab_id" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>{vendor}</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="sectionid" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>XYZ</label>
            <tab>tab_id</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Modulename::sectionid_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Now you have to set default value
for that create **config.xml** file at app/code/{vendor}/{modulename}/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <sectionid>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <display_text>XYZ</display_text>
            </general>
        </sectionid>
    </default>
</config>
```

This will display configuration in admin. After that you have to fetch value of enable/disable in controller using helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your code under this below condition.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
if($state->getAreaCode() != 'backend') 
{
  /* apply your code in here */
}
```